# Solr slave replication server won't start

Tags: crash, solr, replication

Hey guys, I have 2 Solr servers set-up, the master is identical to the slave except for the 4 lines of XML that make it a master.

The slave however errors when you try to start it, I have the following set-up to make it a slave:

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >
<lst name="slave">
<str name="masterUrl">http://10.1.2.196:8080/solr/replication</str>
<str name="pollInterval">00:00:20</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

When I comment out the entire request handler for /replication it works fine but with it Solr throws and error and refuses to start.

The error dump is here:

SEVERE: Could not start SOLR. Check solr/home property
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.SnapPuller.createHttpClient(SnapPuller.java:110)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.SnapPuller.(SnapPuller.java:138)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler.inform(ReplicationHandler.java:775)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:486)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.(SolrCore.java:589)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:137)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3838)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:593)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1484)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329)
    ... 35 more
03/11/2010 2:11:12 AM org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener newSearcher
INFO: QuerySenderListener sending requests to Searcher@207ff5b6 main
03/11/2010 2:11:12 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.SnapPuller.createHttpClient(SnapPuller.java:110)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.SnapPuller.(SnapPuller.java:138)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler.inform(ReplicationHandler.java:775)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:486)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.(SolrCore.java:589)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:137)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3838)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:593)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1484)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329)
    ... 35 more

It is also worth noting that both servers are IDENTICAL other than those lines in the config.

Has anyone encountered this before?

The servers themselves use a custom dataDir

```
<dataDir>/var/lib/solr/data</dataDir>   ... 35 more
```

Comment: it says that you are missing commons-logging. Have you check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Ubuntu didn't add /usr/share/java to the Tomcat class path.

Comment: Profanity is not appreciated here.

Comment: you should answer your question on the mailing list too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This question & answer were extremely helpful for me. However, I couldn't track down the 'correct' way to add /usr/share/java to the CLASSPATH as seen by Tomcat, so I worked around it by symlinking commons-logging.jar into Solr's lib directory:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/java/commons-logging.jar /usr/share/solr/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging.jar
```

I would love to know how to accomplish this in a more graceful fashion. Any tips or input?

Comment: I added it to /etc/tomcat6/catalina.properties - common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,/var/lib/tomcat6/common/classes,/var/lib/tomcat6/common/*.jar,/usr/share/java/*.jar